# Better way to convert JSON to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert a JSON file in to a Pandas dataframe. The JSON file looks like following:

```
{ "ABC":[
   {"AAA":2},
   {"BBB":12},
   {"CCC":12}
 ],
   "DEF":{"X":3, "Y":3,"Z":4}
}
```

Basically, this is a nested dictionary where some of the elements are list and those lists may further contain dictionaries or lists. The nest level could be 20+.

I have written a recursive function to convert all list objects in the file to dictionary and then use `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` to convert it to a pandas dataframe.

I wonder if there is any better way to do this, because it looks to me this is a common problem. I wonder if there is already a package that does this. Appreciate it.

Comment: I believe your approach is what is supposed to be done in these cases. dataframes are bidemensional by definition. By nesting dicts, you virtually add "dimensions" to your data, and you have somehow to normalize it to have two dimensions. `pd.io.json.json_normalize` doesn't to that by default with lists of objects, and since you have 20+ (and likely variable) depth, a recursive approach to normalization sounds pretty reasonable

Comment: Can you show your recursive function? No way to offer a better way to flatten that JSON without seeing it.  `itertools` is likely the best package to go after such data.  While you have mixed types, [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254279/why-doesnt-python-have-a-flatten-function-for-lists) is interesting discourse on the topic.